# How to Use javascript inside a php while loop for displaying map markers

Tags: javascript, php

How do i show multiple database entries in loop ? So that it looks like this:

[image]

But with multiple markers.

I'm not able to loop javascript in php to show multiple markers. Is it possible to do so?

```
dataProvider: {
    map: "worldLow",
    images: [
    <?php include ('query.php');
     while($row= mysql_fetch_array($fetch)){
        $cty = $row['city'];
        $lat = $row['lati'];
        $lon = $row['longi'];
        }?>
        {
        zoomLevel: 5,
        scale: 0.5,
        title: "<?php echo $cty;?>",
        latitude: <?php echo $lon;?>,
        longitude: <?php echo $lat;?>
    }]
}
```

Comment: pre odrer code first

Comment: The echo must be inside of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to use `json_encode` function so as to avoid problems with extra quotes and other symbols:

```
dataProvider: {
    map: "worldLow",
    <?php include ('query.php');
    // store all markers here
    $markers = array();
    while ($row= mysql_fetch_array($fetch)) {
        // add new marker data
        $markers[] = array(
            'zoomLevel' => 5,
            'scale' => 0.5,
            'title' => $row['city'],
            'latitude' => $row['lati'],
            'longitude' => $row['longi'],
        );
    }?>
    images: <?=json_encode($markers)?>
}
```

For further debugging - use developers console and/or see rendered javascript.